# Difference between 'headstrong' and 'strong-minded'?

Tags: differences, synonyms

I can read the dictionary definitions myself, of course:

[strong-minded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strong-minded):

> Someone who is strong-minded is determined and unwilling to change their opinions and beliefs:
>
> *You'll have to be strong-minded if you're going to push the changes through.*

[headstrong](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/headstrong):

> very determined to do what you want without listening to others:
>
> *She was a headstrong child, always getting into trouble.*

So from these, headstrong has a more negative connotation, more or less meaning stubborn in *inappropriate* circumstances, whereas strong-minded might mean tenacity in general, perhaps with positive tint. Is this a good summary of the distinction, or am I inferring too much from these definitions and the terms are more liberally interchangeable in common discourse?

---

N.B. If google is not mistaken, 'strong-minded' sees less usage than 'headstrong' (or 'strong-willed' nowadays), perhaps because 'strong-minded' is more ambiguous.

[image]

But simply looking at n-grams doesn't help with context.

Comment: You have it right, IMO.  Headstrong is often used as a slightly less offensive characterization than "stubborn".  I see "strong-minded" as either being a compliment or a carefully ambiguous put-down - depending on who is saying it and under what circumstances.

Comment: What @KristinaLopez said. Think *head*, as in head-butting, versus *mind*.

Comment: They overlap and *strong-minded* to me suggests determination, irrelevant to motivation:
 (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=strong-minded&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=strong-minded&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.4463j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

*Headstrong* suggests determination *equivalent to* motivation (https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&ei=-K06Ws2zLKiZgAaH5J6ADg&q=headstrong&oq=headstrong&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1l2j0l3j0i46k1j46l2j0l4.118080.120318.0.121198.10.10.0.0.0.0.135.1063.4j6.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.10.1063...0i131k1j0i131i67k1.0.mRmWHcnxU6o)

Comment: Note that the Ngram results do **not** compare the frequency of occurrence of 'headstrong', 'strong-willed', and 'strong-minded', but rather the frequency of occurrence of 'headstrong', 'strong - willed', and 'strong - minded'. That's why the [Ngram graph results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=headstrong%2Cstrong-minded%2Cstrong-willed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) include the labels 'Replaced strong-minded with [strong - minded] to match how we processed the books.' ...

Comment: ... and 'Replaced strong-willed with [strong - willed] to match how we processed the books.' And it's why there are links to matches for 'headstrong' across the specified date range, but no links to matches for 'strong-minded' and 'strong-willed'. In short, Ngram can't provide meaningful frequency results for hyphenated terms, and the results shown in the chart above are therefore unintelligible if not altogether meaningless.

Comment: To me, *headstrong* connotes *impulsive*.

Answer (score 1):

Strong minded means to have strong mind about a particular thing. For example, your mum asks you to drop the money you are holding down but because of your strong mind you will not put it down. While headstrong is when you want to do what is in your mind and nobody can stop you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you can link to a source that *strong-minded* is more of a compliment, and *headstrong* more of an insult, you have a solid first answer. You could even go for "When it's a man, he's called strong-minded. Woman? Headstrong."